# Why I have empty record in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

In our system they asked us to add research interest but when we add new user, we should assign an interest to him/her. It's adding successfully to the database table, we have problem which is we get zero record in the interest_id database table, why?

Here all research interest added successfully to database:

[image]

As you see in picture below when admin add a new user he chooses multiple interests and assign them to a user:

[image]

Here is screenshot of user profile as you can see interests that admin assigned to new user:

[image]

The problem is that it don't write interest id to database?

Below you can see the codes and SQL table:

```
<p>
      <label>Research Areas</label>
      <select name="interest_id[]" class="small-input" multiple>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM research_interest ORDER BY name ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
            {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
      </select>
    </p>
```

Here is also codes for MySQL:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {

        case 'user_add':
            $user_id            = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['user_id']);
            $email              = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
            $password           = rand_pass(8);
            $title_id           = intval($_POST['title_id']);
            $user_type_id       = intval($_POST['usertype_id']);
            $department_id      = intval($_POST['department_id']);
            $view_publication   = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['publication']);
            $referee            = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['referee']);
            $gender             = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['gender']);
            $creation_date      = date('Y.m.d');

            //Interest
            if(!empty($_POST['interest_id']) && is_array($_POST['interest_id'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['interest_id'] as $interest)
                    {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO user_interest (user_id, interest_id)
                        VALUES  ('$user_id', '$interest')";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                    }
            }

            //SQL Query
            $query = "INSERT INTO user (user_id, email, title, user_type_id, department_id, referee, gender, password, view_publication, creation_date)
                        VALUES  ('$user_id', '$email', '$title_id', '$user_type_id', '$department_id', '$referee', '$gender', '$password', '$view_publication', '$creation_date')";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location = "mail.php?action=user_mail&user_id='.$user_id.'"';
            echo '</script>';
        break;

    }
}
```

And this is a user_interest table shows that these three research IDs assign to user 1

[image]

but here it show that interest_id is zero , it don't shows ids of research interest that added to user 1

[image]

Comment: what is the name of that last table you have pictured ?

Comment: You should check `mysqli_error($link)` after you insert the research interests. It will tell you if there's something going wrong. My guess is that there's a foreign key constraint in place and you need to insert the user before you insert the interests.

Comment: You have two tables where you relate users to interests?  Why? Your code clearly only updates two tables, so I don't know hwy you would expect to have a third table updated with this data.

Comment: Dear @lagbox that table name is "user"

Comment: Dear @MikeBrant I have 3 tables one user table which is last one , and second is research_interest table which is for adding new research interest to system, and the third table is for user_interest which is showing which research interests assign to the user!

Answer (score 0):

You are not including `interest_id` in your Insert query to the `users` table. So the table is assigning a default value of `0`.

Comment: Dear @lagbox I have inserted as you can see after comment line **//Interest**

Comment: you may be runnning the query. But your query is missing the interest_id field. Can you not see that ??

Answer (score 0):

You're not inserting anything into the "interest_id" column in the second query so it's defaulting to zero.  It looks like you're trying to set up a many to many relationship (one user can have many interests and one interest can belong to many users). In that case you'll need to set up a junction table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to handle the relationship.